# Softlayer API to get virtual guest owner

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any API to get owner(user who has provisioned a virtual guest) of a virtual guest?
I can only see users having access to a virtual guest API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following request using filters:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={   "virtualGuests": {     "billingItem": {       "orderItem": {         "order": {           "userRecord": {             "username": {               "operation": "myUserName"             }           }         }       }     }   } }&objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.username]

Method: GET
```

**EDIT**

Additionally to get Bare Metal Servers related to `“username”`, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectFilter={   "hardware": {     "billingItem": {       "orderItem": {         "order": {           "userRecord": {             "username": {               "operation": "myUsername"             }           }         }       }     }   } }&objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.username]
Method: GET
```

If you know the `server Id`, use `“object masks”` to get more information than by default, example:

**Virtual Guest:**

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtual_guest_Id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,billingItem[id,orderItem[id,order[userRecord[id,username]]]]]
Method: GET
```

**Hardware:**

```
https://[usrename]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/[hardware_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,billingItem[id,orderItem[id,order[userRecord[id,username]]]]]
Method: GET
```

**Some references:**

[REST](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest)

[Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Filters)

[Time for a REST, Everyone](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/klaude/Time-REST-Everyone)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is perfect :)

Comment: Similarly is there any way to get details for a baremetal servers I own?

Comment: Also this API works if I know the user name of device owner. What if I have device ID and I want to know the owner of the device based on the device ID?

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj, I added more requests in the answer (section: EDIT) that can help you. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

SoftLayer_User_Customer:getVirtualGuests gives all the virtual guests I have access to and not the ones which I actually provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method please:

[SoftLayer_Account::getVirtualGuests](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests)