# How can i get the list of virtual servers created by a specific user?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to get the list of VMs created by a specific user.
Does SoftLayer provide any API for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this request for retrieving the list of virtual guests created by a user’s username:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[billingItem[orderItem[order[userRecord[username]]]]]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"billingItem":{"orderItem":{"order":{"userRecord":{"username":{"operation":"$someUsername"}}}}}}}
Method: GET
```

Note: Replace **$username**, **$apiKey** and **$someUsername** with your data

Additional helpful links:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Filters

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

https://softlayer.github.io/ruby/determining_device_owners/

Here's also a great answer related to your question that's got remarkable information:

[Softlayer API to get virtual guest owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695446/softlayer-api-to-get-virtual-guest-owner)